# Initializing with useState after UseEffect returns : Is that possible?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have two React questions.

Using useEffect I am calling an api:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  //API get call
},[]);
```

The result of the api is stored in array.

Question 1: I know useEffect is asynchronous method, but is there any way for me to use useState to initialize values of  dropdown after useEffect returns?

Question 2: How can I initialize the values of  inside a forEach loop with the values of the array?

Comment: Sure, set the state in the `useEffect` callback and it'll be available to you on the next re-render.

Answer (score 3):

After the API call in `useEffect` call the set state for the `useState` you are saving to. For example:

```
const [state, setState] = useState([]);

const someFetch = async () => {
 // using JS fetch API
 const result = await fetch("getFetchSomeData");
 // assuming the state is in the form of an array
 setState(result.json())
}

useEffect(() => }{
   someFetch();
});

return (
  // rendering the array of fetched state this will update on next render after fetch
  <div>{state}</div>
):
```

Answer (score 1):

Question 1

I would probably do something like this:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(undefined);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const data = await /* API call */
      setData((prevVal) => data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }

    getData();
  }, []);
  
  if (loading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;

  if (!loading && !data) return <h1>Error!</h1>;

  return (
    /* your component */
  );
}
```

In essence, you have to play around the "asynchrony" aspect of the hooks.

Question 2

You did not say what you want to initialize, but I am assuming a component of some sort requires the values from the API. The following example uses HTML `select` element.  Use `map()`.

```
<select>
{
  data && data.map(({value, label}, index) => (
    <option key={index} value={value}>{label}</option>
  ))
}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: I know useEffect is asynchronous method, but is there any way for me to use useState to initialize values of dropdown after useEffect returns?

No, we can't initialize the useState after the useEffect runs. `useEffect` hook always runs both after the first render and after every update. We need to have the initialized value for the state at first render as well. Then later when useEffect run we can simply update the state by setting it.

```
function App(){

 const [stateVariable, setStateVariable] = useState(null);
 
 useEffect(() => {

   async function fetchApiCall(){
    fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(data => setStateVariable(data));
   }
  fetchApiCall(); // function call

 },[]);

}
```

> Question 2: How can I initialize the values inside a forEach loop with the values of the array?

Now we have our data in our stateVariable. Most probably the data which comes from the API is in an array of objects[JSON].

`Array.prototype.map()` function might be helpful here. According to mdn [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map),

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
function processEachElement(element, index){
  return <li key={index}>{element}</li>;
}

const newData = data.map(processEachElement);
// Now the newData is an array of `JSX.Elements`. Remember, not an array of objects.
```

so, the final code is given below,

```
function App() {
  const [stateVariable, setStateVariable] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchApiCall() {
      fetch("http://example.com/movies.json")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => setStateVariable(data));
    }
    fetchApiCall(); // function call
  }, []);

  function processEachElement(element, index) {
    return <li key={index}>{element}</li>;
  }

  const newData = data.map(processEachElement);

  return <ul>{newData}</ul>;
}
```